# SharePoint 2013 Online - IRM + Edit?

Tags: sharepoint-online, irm

I have searched and searched and still can't seem to find an answer! 
Hello all! I'm fairly new to the SharePoint world altogether. 
A little background on my ability: 
My organization is somewhat small and limited. It was the decision of the top few that brought SharePoint to us. Needless to say, one thing led to another and I am now the Admin to ours. With one week of very beginner training, I am here trying to set up intranet style sites for departments that want very specific things. Just keep in mind that I may need advice in layman's terms.

I am trying to set a specified doc library to allow my end user to edit an excel doc in the browser but remove their ability to print or save any of the documents on their local machine.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

Documents in an RMS protected library, or a document that has been RMS protected prior to upload cannot be edited in Office Online (Word, Excel, etc.). They must be opened in the client application in order to edit them.

Comment: Is there a way to disable the print/save function in the browser view without the use of RMS?

Comment: No, there is not.